# How to show Year Dropdown first and Month dropdown 2nd in Jquery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

i am using jquery Ui datepicker, :

How to show **Year Dropdown first** and **Month dropdown 2nd** in Jquery Datepicker

i want to show something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

There is no straight forward solution for this but you can add this to your css

```
.ui-datepicker-month{
    float: right !important;
}
```

i believe it will do the trick

Comment: you have to give the year a position too because otherwise it will overlap the box i guess?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the option `showMonthAfterYear:true`

i.e.

```
jQuery('input[name=calender]').datepicker({
     changeYear:true,
     changeMonth:true,
     showMonthAfterYear:true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the format.

So change this (default)

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

to this, if you haven't specified this. add it to your code.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ altFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
```

Get or set the altFormat option, after initialization:

```
// getter
var altFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "altFormat" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "altFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

As described here 
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat

You can change the theme with the themeroller:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/